# How to check if the the variable matches ANY of the element in the ArrayList ? (Java)

Tags: java

The question could be unclear, so I will explain what I want to ask.

I have a condition that looks really messy :

```
if (( (startX - endX) == 1 && (startY - endY) == 1 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == 1 && (startY - endY) == 0 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == 1 && (startY - endY) == -1 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == 0 && (startY - endY) == 1 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == 0 && (startY - endY) == -1 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == -1 && (startY - endY) == 1 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == -1 && (startY - endY) == 0 ) ||
                ( (startX - endX) == -1 && (startY - endY) == -1 ))))
```

To refactor this, I made a List of the Points that contain those positions ( (1, 0), (1, -1), etc.)

```
    ArrayList<Point> kingMoveRange = new ArrayList<Point>();

    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(1, 0)); 
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(0, -1));
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(0 , 1));
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(-1, -1));
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(-1, 1));
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(1, -1));
    kingMoveRange.add(new Point(1, 1));
```

Looks like above.

But I am not sure how to write something like

```
"If (startX - endX) and (startY - endY) matches ANY one of the pairs in the list "
```

I tried to look for the documentation of ArrayList, but wasn't able to find a clear one to do this.

Comment: you can use contains method for checking a match in a list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about simplifying your original `if` condition to something like:

```
 if (((startX != endX) || (startY != endY)) && // Check we've moved
     ((Maths.abs(startX - endX) <= 1) && (Maths.abs(startY - endY) <= 1))) { // Check we haven't moved far
      // Valid King move
 }
```

Comment: You also need to exclude startX == endX && startY == endY

Comment: @IvanDubrov So, something like && ((startX != endX) && (startY != endY)) ?

Comment: @user6792790 rather && (startX != endX || startY != endY).

Comment: That is just preventing to move to its current location, right?

Answer (score 4):

You could implement an `equals` method for class `Point` (which is btw misnamed since it represents a coordinate difference) and then use

```
kingMoveRange.contains(new Point(startX - endX, startY - endY))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use contains method of ArrayList , for your code snippet it could be like

```
Point PointToCheck = new Point((startX - endX), (startY - endY));
 if(kingMoveRange.contains(PointToCheck)) {
 // TODO for true
  }
```

if it doesn't work then you may have to Override equals method of Point class

Comment: You reversed order. The *core* thing to think about in your approach is that `equals()` method. "Default" equals() will not help him.

Comment: i haven't used Point class so i dont know about its default equals method

Comment: With regard to you attempting to translate [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48416976/5211833) just now: please don't do that. If you translate their post for them, you cannot be certain that they actually speak enough English to understand any English comments or answers directed at them, nor can you be certain that they speak enough English to judge which of the answers, if any, is the correct one for them. Please see [How do I deal with non-English content?
](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/5211833) on meta, especially the first answer.